# Set duration for Focus/DND on macOS

Tags: macos, keyboard, settings, do-not-disturb, focus

My MacBook Air has a Focus/Do Not Disturb/DND/crescent moon physical key that I press to activate that mode.

It used to activate until night time or until the next morning but now it just activates for 30 minutes or so.

I've tried to manually change the duration of activation and that works for the day, but the following day it goes back to only activating for 30 mins.

[image: Focus settings from the top menu bar]

[Official support documents](https://support.apple.com/en-us/guide/mac-help/mchl999b7c1a/mac) haven't been very helpful.

How do I set this key to activate Focus mode for a specified period longer than 30 mins?